# How do you get (editvalue) from RepositoryItemLookUpEdit (no active editor )

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

or enabled ??

ex:

```
if RepositoryItemLookUpEdit1.EDITVALUE = 1 then
RepositoryItemLookUpEdit222.enabled = false
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do and make clear question that what have you implemented that causing problem. A short snippet is not enough to understand the problem...

Comment: thank you,, I want to know the value of RepositoryItemLookUpEdit1

Comment: It does not have a value. Where are you using RepositoryItemLookUpEdit?